# Touchpad Not Working 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10. When I load Ubuntu the touchpad works fine. After a minute or when I sign in (which ever comes first) the touchpad freezes. I have tried commands and editing files. Is there anything else I can try. I am on a Dell Inspiron 15 5555 if that makes a difference.

Some info:

- [`xinput list`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kecq9.png)
- [`dmesg` output after the touchpad ceases to work](//paste.ubuntu.com/23390569/)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `xinput list`? I'd also be curious if there are any related kernel messages from around when the touchpad ceases to work. You can capture them (after the touchpad ceases to work) in a file `~/dmesg.log` with the command `sudo dmesg > ~/dmesg.log` and upload that file to a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/). Thanks.

Comment: I hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so far. I don't know much about touchpad configuration but I'm sure that information will help someone with more knowledge. From what little I can tell from the kernel log this looks like a driver bug.